# iam trying to make an associative arry with key value pair from a for loop variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

iam trying to make an associative arry with key value pair from a for loop variable. i have added a code and is as below.

```
  var applicationTabId = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var currentApp = tabs[i]['url'];
        var tabid = tabs[i]['id'];
        applicationTabId = {[currentApp] : JSON.stringify(tabid)};
        }
```

it outputs only one array element like {"amazon": 15} i need to get all the elements. Please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the value of tabs?

Comment: There is no PHP in this question, please dont spam tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting **applicationTabId** in each iteration. Try this:

```js
var applicationTabId = {};
var tabs = [{"url": "amazon", "id": 15}, {"url": "google", "id": 16}]
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var currentApp = tabs[i]['url'];
        var tabid = tabs[i]['id'];
        applicationTabId[currentApp] = JSON.stringify(tabid);
    }

console.log(applicationTabId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are still overwriting data in your variable with last row in your code. So in your varibale is only the last one item. Try this:

```
 var applicationTabId = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            var currentApp = tabs[i]['url'];
            var tabid = tabs[i]['id'];
            applicationTabId[currentApp] = JSON.stringify(tabid);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just assigning value to a variable. Use Push if you want to create an array of objects

```
applicationTabId.push({currentApp : JSON.stringify(tabid)});
```

This will give you array of objects like

```
[
  {"amazon": 15},
  {"yahoo": 16}  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign` and `map` over tabs array will give desired object.

```js
var tabs = [
  { url: "msft", id: 1 },
  { url: "google", id: 2 }
];

const res = Object.assign({}, ...tabs.map(({ url, id }) => ({ [url]: id })));

console.log(res);
```